# Accessing elements of a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Ruby 2.15
```

I defined the following hash:

```
test = Hash.new
test["foo"] = {
  'id' => 5,
  'lobbyist_id' => 19,
  'organization_id' => 8
}
```

If I do

```
test.each do |t|
  print t["id"] 
end
```

I get:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
    from (irb):1571:in `[]'
```

How do I access the elements, using an each loop?

## Answer:

```
test.each do |t|
   t.each do |t1|
     puts t1["id"]
   end  
end
```

Comment: if you want just value of an `id` then why you are using each loop? you can get id directly by using `test['foo']['id']`.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a Hash, iteration is made through key first, then value. So have your block use what you need.

```
test.each do |key|
  puts key
end

test.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value
end
```

There are also

```
test.each_key do |key|
  puts key
end

test.each_value do |value|
  puts value
end
```

---

Sidenote: `id` is inside `test["foo"]`, so maybe you'd need 2 loops

---

To get `id` from your hash directly:

```
test["foo"]["id"]

test["foo"].each {|k, v| puts "#{k}: #{v}" }
```

Comment: Please add some description

Comment: @apneadiving My question, is how do I get id from value (to use your example)

Comment: Yes, a second loop was needed. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In your example we assume you've previously done:

```
test = Hash.new
```

In your example variable `test` is a hash and `foo` is a key who's value contains a hash of key values.  If you want to target those, you'll need to loop over them

```
test['foo'].each do |k,v|
  puts "my key is #{k}"
  puts "it's value is {v}
end
```

If you want to do both at the same time:

```
test.each do |k,v|
  puts "base hash key #{k}"
  puts "base hash value #{v}"
  v.each do |kk,vv|
    puts "key #{kk}"
    puts "value #{vv}"
  end
end
```